# Django how deactive User Account

Tags: python, django

Let's say I want to deactivate the specific User Account when the user clicks *Deactivate Account* button.

How would I do this?

\\views.py

```
def delete_view(request):

    profile = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeleteUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile.is_active = False
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = DeleteUserForm(instance=profile)

    return render(request, 'delete.html', {'form': form, 'profile': profile})
```

\\forms.py

```
class DeleteUserForm(forms.Form):
    delete = forms.CharField(
        label='', max_length=0).widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

The code was just an attempt but does not work because of the instance, so you can think away from the instance

Comment: `request.user.is_active = False` and then `requests.user.save()`

Answer (score 0):

From the `official` documentation [is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.is_active)

> Designates whether this user account should be considered active. We recommend that you set this flag to False instead of deleting accounts; that way, if your applications have any foreign keys to users, the foreign keys won’t break

You can set `is_active` status to `False` of that `specific user`. You can `deactivate` that particular user by providing `username` of that user in your `views` since `username` is unique you can pass `username` and `deactivate` that particular user as shown below:

```
def delete_view(request, username):    
    try:
        u = User.objects.get(username=username)
        u.is_active = False
        u.save()
        return HttpResponse() #<--- after successful deactivation of user           
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse() #<--- if user does not exists with provided username
    except Exception as e: 
        return HttpResponse() #<---- if some exception occurs
```